# Advanced Math - Solving Optimal Sets Using a Program

Tags: algorithm, math, set

I want to develop a program which analyzes sets.  I think the best way I can describe the program is using an example.  For those of you familiar with toggle coverage that is the purpose of this application.

The goal is to reach 100% coverage.
TestA stresses X% of the chip, but % doesn't matter, what matters is which set of pins/portions of the chip is stressed.  So let us say TestA stresses setA and TestB stresses setB, so on and so forth for Y number of tests until we reach 100% coverage.

Here is the problem, we want to reduce Y to Y' such that Y' is the minimum ammount of tests required.  How? Lets say TestA can be eliminated because by running TestB, C, D we obtain the set which TestA would have covered.

The question I have is, I want to do research on this area (IEEE articles and so on) but don't know what to search? I am looking for titles, papers, etc. to help me determine an algorithm.  If you have 1000 tests, I don't want to say "Can I eliminate testA with B? no? What about B+C? no? What about B+C+D?" In addition to being very slow, it doesn't account for the fact that sure A might be replaced by B+C+D, but A would have significantly helped with removing D+E+F.

I'd appreciate help in going in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like a variation of the [Set Cover Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), which is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete).

**Set Cover Problem:**

Given a universe of elements `U`, and a set of sets: `S = {X | X is a subset of U}` - find minimal subset `S'` of `S` such that the union of all elements in `S'` is `U`, and `S'` is minimal.

Since the problem is NP-Complete, there is no known polynomial solution to it, and most believe one does not exist.

You can try approximation algorithms (formulate the problem as linear integer programming problem and use integer programming approximation solution), or some heuristics, such as [greedy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Greedy_algorithm).

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful :)  I'll give this some thought and maybe post later with some thoughts on the algorithm I come up with.